Is there a way to combine these (mod_rewrite and mod_alias) rules in .htaccess to avoid multiple redirects?
This is what my .htaccess file is like:
#unrelated stuff

Redirect 301 /old_1/ /new_1/
#lots of unrelated rules
Redirect 301 /old_999/ /new_999/

#this matters:
Redirect 301 /a/b/page.php /a/b/page/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #a bunch of unrelated rules here

    #this is used to escape multiple slashes:
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !http(s|)://
    RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]

    #a bunch of unrelated rules here
</IfModule>

#unrelated stuff

It works well when removing multiple slashes or redirecting /a/b/page.php to /a/b/page/ is needed. But when I try /a/b//page.php it does 2 redirects: /a/b//page.php to /a/b/page.php, and then /a/b/page.php to /a/b/page/. Is there a way to avoid that in my case?
During my research I found out that mod_rewrite executes first, so people advice to move rules made for specific pages inside mod_rewrite block (syntax changes a bit obviously). So I tried putting
RewriteRule ^/a/b//page.php /a/b/page/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /a/b//page.php /a/b/page/ [R=301,L]

and
RewriteRule ^a/b//page.php /a/b/page/ [R=301,L]

inside mod_rewrite block right after
RewriteBase /

despite this tool says I'm fine using the last option but redirect checker still shows an additional step.

The following will do what you want:
# This rule handles both normal and double slashes, and redirects /a/b/page.php to /a/b/page/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/b/page\.php$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} // [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /a/b/page/ [R=301,L]

It will trigger for either condition and do a single redirect to the desired destination.

Edit -

Based on your follow-up question, I've edited the answer. You can combine both rules to apply to have a single redirect. The updated code would be:
# Handle normalization of slashes and specific path redirection in one step
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/b/(?:page\.php|/+page\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /a/b/page/ [R=301,L]

# General rule to normalize multiple slashes for all other requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !http(s|)://
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]


Hey there, thanks for your answer! Your code works like a charm when I comment out my common multislash rule which is
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !http(s|)://     RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
but still redirects 2 times when I leave it as is. Am I missing something?

Each rule acts sequentially. So if the 1st rule applies correctly, it will redirect to another location. Once redirected, the 1st rule no longer applies, so the 2nd rule kicks in.

Thanks a lot, your edited code does the trick!
